# Adding "Lookup in the dictionary" in the pop-up list in Firefox?

Tags: safari, firefox

Is it possible to add the item "Look up in Dictionary" in the right-click popup menu when you have selected a word on a web page, in Firefox (just like it is available in safari) ?

[image: safari's screen shot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a firefox addon to add this in the context menu: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/look-up-in-dictionary-7261/

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome here. ;)

Comment: The add-on seems to have been removed as of 21 Jan 2020.

Comment: Found a new add-on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dictionary-anyvhere/

Answer (score 0):

As of now (Dec 1 2014), although the option is not present in right-click menu, three-finger dictionary lookup works perfectly fine in my Firefox (Developer Edition 35)