# How do I use the right click look up feature everywhere on my Mac including Firefox?

Tags: firefox, dictionary, contextual-menu, look-up

I want to be able to double click on a word in my Firefox Browser and right click it and select look up to translate it. (or even better, double click and it shows the English dictionary explanation)

But somehow Firefox doesn't allow that.

- Firefox version = 72.0.1 (64-bit)
- macOS Catalina version = 10.15.2 (19C57)

How can I get this to happen?

Comment: What version of macOS and Firefox. Please edit so we can [decide if another question covers your situation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15565/adding-lookup-in-the-dictionary-in-the-pop-up-list-in-firefox) well enough to combine forces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of keep looking for solution that allows me to use the native Mac OS look up feature, I use the Firefox add-on Dictionary Anywhere instead:

https://github.com/meetDeveloper/Dictionary-Anywhere

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dictionary-anyvhere/